SerpAPIWrapper Output Items Count Doesn't Match Parameter
from langchain_community.utilities.serpapi import SerpAPIWrapper

search = SerpAPIWrapper(params={
    "engine": "google_shopping",
    "num":5
})

query = "Rice Cooker"
results = search.run(query)

Is not returning 5 items. It only gives 3. Why is that? How to return 5 items?

The num parameter is a suggestion to Google, and in some cases, Google may not return the exact number of results specified in the num param.
The other possibility is some results were missing due to an issue in langchain.
I work for SerpApi so if you want us to look into what might have happened on the SerpApi side, please contact us through our live chat on https://serpapi.com/ or write to us at contact@serpapi.com
We'll be happy to help.
